# How do you set a field value without knowing its type?

Tags: java, reflection

I am attempting to set a field value on a class that is already compiled using a class loader. I am having trouble. I keep getting an error that looks like:

```
Can not set abc.ModelOne field abc.ModelTwo.modelOne to java.lang.Class
```

It doesn't look like its recognizing the object as its type. I even went as far as casting the object as its type but still no avail.

```
Object value = field.getType().cast(p);
field.set(clazz, value);
```

Any guidance would be awesome! Thank you.

Comment: `field.set(clazz, value);` <- first parameter should be an instance of that class.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing new instance. Is there a way to hook into a java classes lifecycle?

Comment: Java Agents might be an option.